# Maven Could not resolve dependencies (Return code is: 409 , ReasonPhrase:Conflict)

Tags: java, maven, war, artifactory

> Failed to execute goal on project lcms.web:

```
    Could not resolve dependencies for project lcms:lcms.web:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: 
    Failed to collect dependencies for [junit:junit:jar:4.9 (test), org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE (compile), commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1 (compile), 
org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE (compile), commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1 (compile), taglibs:standard:jar:1.1.2 (compile), commons-dbcp:commons-
dbcp:jar:20030825.184428 (compile), commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:20030825.183949 (compile), net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:jar:1.3.1 (compile), org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework.security:spring-security-cas:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE (compile), org.jasig.cas.client:cas-client-core:jar:3.1.12 (compile), com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1 (compile), org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1 (compile), org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1 (compile), javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1 (provided), cglib:cglib:jar:2.2 (compile), antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7 (compile), lcmsdaomodel:lcms.dao.model:jar:1.1.1 (compile), 
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.5 (compile),
 com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.5 (compile), commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3.1 (compile), org.apache.axis:axis-jaxrpc:jar:1.4 (compile), axis:axis:jar:1.4 (compile), org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.10-FINAL (compile), com.jolbox:bonecp:jar:0.8.0.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE (compile), commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1 (compile), net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:jdk15:2.4 (compile), org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.0.1 (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for lcmsdaomodel:lcms.dao.model:jar:1.1.1: Could not transfer artifact lcmsdaomodel:lcms.dao.model:pom:1.1.1 from/to snapshots (http://******/artifactory/ext-snapshot-local): Failed to transfer file: http://*******/artifactory/ext-snapshot-local/lcmsdaomodel/lcms.dao.model/1.1.1/lcms.dao.model-1.1.1.pom. Return code is: 409 , ReasonPhrase:Conflict. -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to resolve RELEASE artifact from a SNAPSHOT repository, therefore Artifactory is sending an error (409 conflict).

You should direct your build to 'libs-releases' virtual repository, or any other virtual repository that holds only releases, so only repositories that hold release artifacts will be involved in the process of RELEASE artifact resolution

You can read [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Repository#MavenRepository-ResolvingArtifactsthroughArtifactory) more about resolution from Artifactory Maven repositories

Comment: Today, i had to upper case my 1.1.0-snapshot version name to 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT to get over the 409 conflict error

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem and clearing out my .m2 directory fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error, I was deploying snapshot and snapshotRepository settings was not included in my main pom's distributionManagement.
fix by adding snapshotRepository

```
    <distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>libs-snapshot</name>
        <url>http://artifactory.private-apps.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your error details,

```
Failed to transfer file: http://*******/artifactory/ext-snapshot-local/lcmsdaomodel/lcms.dao.model/1.1.1/lcms.dao.model-1.1.1.pom.
Return code is: 409 , ReasonPhrase:Conflict. -> [Help 1]
```

You have deployed a release version of lcms.dao.model in *ext-snapshot-local* which is only used to deploy manual snapshot of libraries. Check artifactory [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Local+Repositories).

1. If `lcms.dao.model` is a released artifact, then login into your artifactory and delete entry for this library in Artifacts -> Tree Browser -> ext-snapshot-local. You need to have released version of this library in your artifactory.
2. If this is snapshot version, you need to version your library as `1.1.1-SNAPSHOT`

Answer (score 0):

I received this error with the archiva repository directory of the artifact being incorrectly set such that archiva didn't have write access.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest solution for many cases is you can delete the specific folder you are having the problem with, from the `.m2` folder. You don't have to delete the entire folder because it might take a lot of time re build it.