# Maven POM file Error in Managing Open-source security and license with WhiteSource Bolt Lab On Azure Devops

Tags: maven, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-pipelines

I got the below-mentioned error in Maven Tasks in the Build Pipeline. Can’t understand this issue. I think the source code needs to update. Do I have to update my POM File for this Project? I'm not a developer. I'm learning Azure DevOps and implementing on the same.

```
[ERROR]
Plugin org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.3-SNAPSHOT or one
of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact
descriptor for
org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:jar:2.3-SNAPSHOT: Could not
transfer artifact
org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:pom:2.3-SNAPSHOT from/to
maven-default-http-blocker (https://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for
repositories: [apache.snapshots (https://repository.apache.or…, default, releases+snapshots)] -> [Help 1]
```

Error screenshot

[image]

Comment: The POM uses a SNAPSHOT version of a plugin. It probably misses the right repository for that. The `maven-default-http-blocker` suggests that maybe someone blocked this on purpose in the `settings.xml`

Answer (score 0):

> Maven POM file Error in Managing Open-source security and license with
> WhiteSource Bolt Lab On Azure Devops

According to the error log, it seems you are trying to deploy a snapshot version into a release only repository.

In your pom, you should set the `<version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>`, but in the error log, you are deploy artifacts to **repo-release**. Hence the conflict.

To resolve this issue, please try to select a snapshot repository instead of a release one in your `pom.xml` or select a release library rather than the snapshot library for your release version.

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42219560/maven-could-not-resolve-dependencies-return-code-is-409-reasonphraseconflic/42223277) for some more details.